# Create a new Excel file based on data in column

Tags: vba, excel

I've spent hours searching and trying different macros with no avail. I'm not new to excel, but new to macros and coding. I have a spreadsheet with departmental data that needs separated by managers name, so it may be distributed to each with only their teams data. Essentially, I need a file for each manager and it to include the corresponding data. The managers name is in column "F". For this week, I have 57 rows of data and columns range from A to I. Is there a macro or a code to use in VBE that I can run to do this automatically? I know I can use sort & filter to copy and paste the data into each additional file but I'm hoping for a macro that will be able to take care of this.

Comment: Definitely possible. If you are using outlook to email it to different managers, the following code might be helpful: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail8.htm

Comment: Hi Pete, is there a way to just have it so that it is saved? I can handle the distribution later on. Also, on the link you sent me, should I be replacing the column that's listed with the corresponding column I want to be filtered? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to distribute it, there are easier ways to split it up. What does you data look like? Is every manager only once in column F? And do you just want to save a new file with that row for each manager? It would be helpful if you could add sample data and a copy of the code you have been working on to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Managers will appear multiple times in column F.  The master spreadsheet will be filled with data on each team. The spreadsheet is tracking errors each person made along with the type of case their working. Essentially, I need a macro that will automatically create a file for each manager in column F. The additional files should copy data for each row that the manager is listed on. I can provide you with a sample spreadsheet if there is somewhere to upload it.

Comment: The below is what I had so far. This allowed me to create new files based on each person in column F, but it doesn't copy the corresponding in the rows. 

Dim lRow As Integer
lRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("F2:F" & lRow)
Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=cell.Value & ".xls"
Next cell
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
Sub test()

Dim My_Range As Range
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim CCount As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim ErrNum As Long
Dim DestRange As Range
Dim Lr As Long

Set My_Range = Range("A1:I" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
My_Range.Parent.Select

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
   My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
FieldNum = 6

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

With ws2
    'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
    My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
    Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

        My_Range.Parent.Select
        'Filter the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
         Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

        'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
        CCount = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                 .Areas(1).Cells.Count
        On Error GoTo 0
        If CCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value: " & cell.Value _
                 & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                 & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                   vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
        Else
            'Add a new worksheet or set a reference to a existing sheet
            If SheetExists(cell.Text) = False Then
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = cell.Value
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                    WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set DestRange = WSNew.Range("A1")
            Else
                Set WSNew = Sheets(cell.Text)
                Lr = LastRow(WSNew)
                Set DestRange = WSNew.Range("A" & Lr + 1)
            End If

            'Copy the visible data to the worksheet
            My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With DestRange
                .Parent.Select
                ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Select
            End With
        End If

        ' Delete the header row if you copy to a existing worksheet
        If Lr > 1 Then WSNew.Range("A" & Lr + 1).EntireRow.Delete

        'Show all data in the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

    Next cell

    'Delete the ws2 sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End With

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

If ErrNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
         & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
         & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
My_Range.Parent.Select
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function SheetExists(SName As String, _
                 Optional ByVal WB As Workbook) As Boolean
'Chip Pearson
On Error Resume Next
If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ThisWorkbook
SheetExists = CBool(Len(WB.Sheets(SName).Name))
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please provide more explanation of your answer than "Maybe".  Comments included in code samples are great, but with a sample this big, breaking it up with deeper explanation is extremely helpful.  Also, based on the last comment, it looks like you may have copied this from Chuck Pearson's site.  Please include references to any copied material, both as a courtesy to the original creator and so that readers can dig deeper into the material.